# Twitching of joints in btMultiBody

Tags: physics, physics-engine, bulletphysics, bullet

I have simple vehicle based on `btMultiBody`. Referring to the attached GIF, its base is the rectangular block in the center and it contains four cylindrical wheels which are attached using `btMultiBody::setupRevolute`. Each wheel contains a joint motor which is configured so that the body rotates on the spot. Everything is working well, however, there is this slight twitching that occurs every half rotation of the vehicle. Does anyone have any ideas regarding where this twitching could be coming from? Note that the red spheres are just markers and don't have a representation inside of the `btMultiBodyDynamicsWorld`. One (possibly) important point, the location of the bodies is being rendered via `btMultibodyLink::m_cachedWorldTransform`, I am not using any motionstates etc.

[image: overhead view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the model was in fact not due to the physics but to the drawing in OpenGL. For OpenGL, we converted the Quaternion into Euler angles and had a too larger margin for detecting and handling gimbal lock. Reducing this margin significantly improved the visualization.